# How to fix this error "Connection Error with MySQL database" in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I an setting up the connection with the **MySQL server**.
This is the code I wrote and got the errors:

```
import mysql.connector as mysql


def user_registration():
     connection_to_mysql = mysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root',
  passwd='aWais$777')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please first trying with double quotes i.e. " " with password parameter passing. If not success then trying double quotes with all passing parameter i.e. host, user and password.

Because of passwd field contains this symbol '$' that's why not accepting.

For more info visit check this code: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_mysql_getstarted.asp

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
  host="localhost",
  user="yourusername",
  passwd="yourpassword"
)

print(mydb)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `password` instead of `passwd` and make sure to specify `database`.